# SQL Server case when and group by to return a value when no rows returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem I can't seem to find an easy solution for. I am trying to write a query that uses a case when statement to return a value based on some counts. In the same query, I also need to return an orderid as I need to utilize the data returned by this for another query.

Below is the query:

```
select CASE WHEN count(name) = 0 THEN '1' ELSE CONVERT(varchar,count(name) + 1) END AS box
, orderid
from order 
where len(name) = 7
and orderid = 'XYZ' 
group by orderid
```

The issue above is that as you can imagine, a row is only returned when a a name with length 7 exists in the data. I need this query to return a valid value regardless of that.

The query should return: `1, XYZ` when no name of length 7 exists. The query does work when a valid 7 length name exists.

What would be the best way of handling this issue? Note that the data can contain multiple names that are below length 7. These names will then change to length 7 after a transaction takes place.

Below is sample data and desired results:

```
NAME     ORDERID
ABC      001
XYZ      001
123      001
OOP      002
LMT      002
```

When I run my query for `orderid = '1'`, the query should return `1, 001`. The data will be constantly changing so initially it was as pictured above. As transactions take place, data will be changed as:

```
    NAME           ORDERID
    ABCABCABC      001
    XYZ            001
    123            001
    OOP            002
    LMT            002
```

At this point, I don't have to worry about my query above because it will return a valid row: `2, 001`

Issue is when the name column us not the right length, the query returns nothing.

Comment: Using data from one query to get data for another query is usually a good indicator of a need for a `JOIN` and possibly better filters. It's much better to make one call to the db to get the data you want than to make multiple calls.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't join it for a filter as if above table/logic is used, a join will return no rows due to no name with length 7 existing. This is resolved once the data exists but up until that point it does not work.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added examples of sample data and desired return

Comment: @Help123 What is the second table you're JOINing to? You may be chasing the wrong rabbit? This may be an XY Problem. Show what you're working with and what you want to end up with. No Records Found is still a valid result, and may best be handled in your application itself. And I still don't think using one query's result to derive another query's results is a very SQLish way to go about things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want this:

```
select convert(varchar(255),
               sum(case when len(name) = 7 and orderid = 'XYZ' then 1 else 0 end) + 1

                   end) as box,
       orderid
from order 
group by orderid;
```

This moves all the filtering logic into the `select`.

If what you want is one row with the counts and an order id which is preferably XYZ but something else if that is not available:

```
select convert(varchar(255),
               sum(case when len(name) = 7 and orderid = 'XYZ' then 1 else 0 end) + 1

                   end) as box,
       coalesce(max(case when orderid = 'XYZ' then orderid end),
                max(orderid)
               ) as orderid
from order 
group by orderid;
```

Comment: I think your first query will work. I removed the orderid from the case clause because I need to return the value of all orders and filter it for the one I need. I'll keep test using that query but from my intiial test it looks good

Comment: can you explain a bit about why the sum is used? Trying to understand the logic behind your solution. Is the sum used on the group of orderid to sum up each returned value for the case statement?

Comment: @Help123 . . . `sum()` is used to count the number of rows that match the conditions that were in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

when no name has lenth 7 then you should use below query

select CASE WHEN count(name) = 0 and len(name)!=7 THEN '1' ELSE CONVERT(varchar,count(name) + 1) END AS box
, orderid
from order 
where orderid = 'XYZ' 
group by orderid

Comment: This query does not work as its returning 2. It's skipping the initial check and going into the ELSE part of the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty ugly but by left joining to a inline view which consists of 1 record,
every record in B gets XYZ so we are guaranteed to have at least 1 record; and if order has names with a length of 7 then we use those values, otherwise order left join will be null and we coalesce the value from the inline view.

Normally I'd do this type of thing in the UI, if no records are returned, handle that in the Presentation layer, not here.

But if you must:

UNTESTED (I can't see a logic flaw yet or a syntax one but I don't have an environment to test)

```
SELECT coalesce(CASE WHEN count(a.name) = 0 
                     THEN '1' 
                     ELSE CONVERT(varchar,count(a.name) + 1) END
               ,b.Box) AS box
     , coalesce(a.orderid,b.orderID)
FROM (SELECT '1' Box, 'xyz' OrderID) b
LEFT join [order] A
 on 1=1
 and len(a.name) = 7
 and a.orderid = 'XYZ' 
GROUP BY coalesce(a.orderid,b.OrderID)
```

Comment: Renamed columns in inlineview b to make it easier to follow.